# Restricting 'Type' parameters in a method/constructor

Tags: c#, generics, types, parameters, attributes

I'd like to pass a `Type` parameter into a constructor. This constructor belongs to an attribute.

That's simple. But how do I constrain this `Type` parameter to sub classes of a particular class only?

So I have a parent class `ParentClass` and two child classes `MyChildClass : ParentClass` and `MyOtherChildClass : ParentClass`.

My attribute looks like this:

```
public class AssociatedTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly Type _associatedType;

    public Type AssociatedType => _associatedType;

    public AssociatedTypeAttribute(Type associatedType)
    {
        if (!associatedType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ParentClass)))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Specified type must be a {nameof(Parentclass)}, {associatedType.Name} is not.");

        _associatedType = associatedType;
    }
}
```

This works, and at runtime it'll throw an exception if the type isn't a `ParentClass` - but runtime is too late.

Is it possible to add some sort of constraint? Can I use generics here or am I right in saying generics are out of bounds since it's the constructor of an attribute?

Note usage:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   [AssociatedType(typeof(MyChildClass))]
   MyEnumValue,
   [AssociatedType(typeof(MyOtherChildClass))]
   MyOtherEnumValue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `Type` and you can't use generics because it is not allowed to extend `Attribute` with a generic class.

The best solution you have is a runtime check and simply ignoring the attribute if the target doesn't match the intended one.

Comment: As I suspected, thanks very much for your answer. I wonder if I'm falling victim to the XY problem here; maybe my whole approach is off. Thanks again.